# How do i center multiple images in a div within a container div( i have tried several methods including: text-align:center and justify-content)

Tags: html, css

Trying to center images in a div within a container div.

here is the html, images are contained within the container div

```
<div class="container">    
   <div class="col"> 
       <img src="../Images/New folder (2)/Blue Tie.jpg" />
       <p>Blue Tie</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col"> 
       <img src="../Images/New folder (2)/Cardigan.jpg" />
       <p>Cardigan</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

here is the css

```
.container{
    display:flex;
    max-width: 350px;
    text-align: center;   
}

.col{
    min-width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;  
}


.col img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: it is a bit unclear what you wanna do. Your .container has a maximum width of 350px. Is it how you want it or is it supposed to get the whole width of the browser? Since the width is 350px the items can not be centered because they already cover the 350 width of the parent

Comment: trying to spread 6 images over a page, but im trying to get the images centered and leave a bit of whitespace to make the page look good

Comment: do you mean something like that? https://jsfiddle.net/pg9fz6rm/2/

Comment: yes, thank you!, please what was wrong with my initial code?

Comment: i ll add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the container should be set to 100% so it can get the whole width. Then you set the container's display to `flex` and you set the `align items` and `justify content` to center so every child is align to center.

Secondly you have to give a specific width to the children otherwise they will equally fill the width of the parent.

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background:lightgrey;
    padding: 2rem 0;
}

.col{
    max-width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;  
}


.col img{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">    
   <div class="col"> 
       <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-hot-air-balloons-flying-260nw-1033306540.jpg" />
       <p>Blue Tie</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col"> 
       <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-hot-air-balloons-flying-260nw-1033306540.jpg" />
       <p>Cardigan</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col"> 
       <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-hot-air-balloons-flying-260nw-1033306540.jpg" />
       <p>Cardigan</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col"> 
       <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-hot-air-balloons-flying-260nw-1033306540.jpg" />
       <p>Cardigan</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col"> 
       <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-hot-air-balloons-flying-260nw-1033306540.jpg" />
       <p>Cardigan</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col"> 
       <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-hot-air-balloons-flying-260nw-1033306540.jpg" />
       <p>Cardigan</p>
   </div>
</div>
```